# Why is element.classname used when classname seems to do the same thing?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Why are these types of selectors used where the p element is specified with a class name (in order to select all p elements with the class name colort)

```
p.colort {
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
<p class="colort">this is a test</p>
```

When this type of selector seems to do the same thing? (specifying the class and assigning it to all p elements that I want it assigned to)

```
.back_color{
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
<p class="back_color">this is a test</p>
```

What is the difference that I'm missing?

Comment: The first selector would only match `p` elements with that class, and would leave all other element types with that same class (should any of those exist) alone … Add `<div class="{same class as the P has here}">should I be violet, then please shoot me.</div>` to your HTML in both cases, and see what difference that makes.

Comment: Thanks that cleared it up for me, and the fact that I was thinking about it too deeply!

Answer (score 1):

**p** is a an element selector. **.colort** is the selector of class. You can have many different elements with class **.colort**. To get specific element you cant use **p.colort**

Although **p.colort** have more weight then **.colort**. If you will use both in code - system will execute p.colort with higher priority.